# Android - Set Location Mode Programmatically on Marshmallow

Tags: android, location, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, android-location

Ever since I've upgraded my device to Android 6.0.1 Marshmallow, Android automatically sets the location mode to **High Accuracy** when apps with the `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission, try to access the location of my device.

Personally, I found it quite annoying as setting the location mode to **High Accuracy** drains my device's battery at a very high rate. So, I need to check every now and then if the location mode has been changed and manually need to change it back to **Battery Saving** mode.

So, I decided to make an app that'll deploy an `IntentService` in the background which'll check every 30 mins if the location mode has been changed to **High Accuracy** and will change it back to **Battery Saving**.

But, the problem the faced while doing that is finding a method that'll let me change the location mode programmatically.

I tried using the following code but without any use:

```
public void ChangeLocationMode() {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(SetLocationModeService.this, "Location Mode Changed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I've also added the following permissions in my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
```

But, this method doesn't seem to work at all.

So, my question here is,

> Is there any way at all to change the Location Mode programmatically in Android Marshmallow (or above)?

If there is any tried and tested method of doing the same, please consider sharing it here.